# Replicating Windows Explorer Change View Control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I want to implement the following control in my application. Is there an existing control out there? If not, can anyone suggest what default control I should base my custom control on.

### Pictures for clarification:

---

### Control on Toolbar

[image]

### Control Mini Menu

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, there is.](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/28/itemscontrol-r-is-for-rob-has-a-customer/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spy to look at the controls in Windows 7 Explorer, you will see that the whole part that contains the toolbar (and the button with this control you like) is of class DirectUIHWND. Now, although you can find some info on the Internet about this class, this class is not documented anywhere by Microsoft so this mean that it might not be available in the next version of windows, so your program will probably not work if you base your code on it.

However, it seems it's a relative simple popup control so it should be easy to implement it in WPF (based on a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control).